# Angular 4 geting data in console.log but not rendering in html

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have these function,  where ever I can access the products data in html and when group this data in other variable then not able to access in html.

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.subscriptions.push(this.searchTerms.pipe(
        //wait for specified interval before passing the event further, helps to make sure http request is only made when user finishes typing.
        debounceTime(CONFIG.searchDebounceInterval),
        //check whether the value has changed or not and passes the event further if value did change.
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        //switch to new search observable each time the term changes
        switchMap((term: string) => {

        })).subscribe(
        httpDataPayload => {
            this.httpDataPayload = httpDataPayload;
            this.bindProducts();
        },
        error => this.handleHttpError(error)
    ));
}

groupProduct(objectArray) {
    let property = this.reportType;
   this.projectsGroup = objectArray.reduce(function (acc, obj) {
        let key = obj[property];
        if (!acc[key]) {
            acc[key] = [];
        }
        acc[key].push(obj);
        return acc;
    }, []);

    console.log(this.projectsGroup);
}


bindProducts(): void {
        this.objPager.callFunction = false;
        let records = this.httpDataPayload.records;

        //if server sent some data, add it to the products array
        if (records) {
            let products: Array<Product> = [];

                for (let i = 0, len = records.length; i < len; i++) {
                    products.push(new Product(records[i].record));
                }
            this.products.next(products);
            this.groupProduct(products);
            this.progressService.hide();
        } else {
            this.handleError(this.httpDataPayload);
            this.noResults = true;
        }
    }
```

Note: objectArray is async data

I get the data in console.log but not rendering in html

this is html code

```
<div class="table-container">{{projectsGroup|json}}</div>
```

Comment: try without `json` pipe

Comment: If this.projectsGroup is a list you have to iterate with ngFor

Comment: If you just want to see raw value, use it without `json` pipe in HTML

Comment: I want to iterate but its showing empty array but in console have these data [Asus: Array(3), Dell: Array(5), Microsoft: Array(3)]
Asus: (3) [Product, Product, Product]
Dell: (5) [Product, Product, Product, Product, Product]
Microsoft: (3) [Product, Product, Product]
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: objectArray is async data

Comment: when does `groupProduct` get called?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: <div class="table-container" *ngIf="projectsGroup">{{projectsGroup | json}}</div>

Comment: Not working, same issue

Comment: @UmashankarSaw I am not sure how `objectArray` is async data? Isn't it simply an array of `Product` objects passed to `groupProduct` method?